# Angular parent component listen to a ng-content child component

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

I want a function to trigger within my parent component when my child component emits an event. The child component is passed into the parent through ng-content. I simplified the code of what I'm trying to do but I can't seem to have the child emit to the parent. I want to pass the child with ng-content because the child component can be a variety of components and not 1 single specific one

Example:

main.ts

```
<parent-component>
  <child-component></child-component>
</parent-component>
```

parent.component.ts

```
<div>
 {{ this.value }}
 <ng-content (updated)="updateParentValue()"></ng-content> <-- this doesn't work
</div>

updateParentValue(value) {
  this.value = value;
}
```

child.component.ts

```
<div>
  <span (click)="updateStuff()">update</span>
</div>

@Output() updated = new EventEmitter();

updateStuff() {
  // Stuff
  this.updated.emit(this.value);
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors on console?

Comment: no errors. it doesn't seem like the event triggers on the ng-content but instead in main. Wondering how to have the event trigger in the parent and not main

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34802210/angular-2-child-component-events-broadcast-to-parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Krim, solved it with that link

main.ts

```
<parent-component>
  <child-component></child-component>
</parent-component>
```

parent.component.ts

```
<div>
 {{ this.value }}
 <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>

@ContentChildren(ChildComponent) childComponents: QueryList<ChildComponent>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.childComponents.forEach((childComponent: ChildComponent) => {
       childComponent.updated.subscribe((item) => this.updateParentValue(item));           
   });
}

updateParentValue(value) {
  this.value = value;
}
```

child.component.ts

```
<div>
  <span (click)="updateStuff()">update</span>
</div>

@Output() updated = new EventEmitter();

updateStuff() {
  // Stuff
  this.updated.emit(this.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only answer is not managing subscriptions. Here I'm using gorgeous **@rx-angular/state** with connect method to manage subscription automatically, but you can manage it manually or use **@ngneat/until-destroy**.

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  const tabChanges$ = this.tabs.changes.pipe(
    tap((tabs: QueryList<TabComponent>) => tabs),
    tap((tabs) => tabs.forEach((tab, index) => (tab.index = index))),
    switchMap((tabs) =>
      merge(...tabs.map((tab, index) => tab.clicked.pipe(map(() => index))))
    ),
    startWith(0),
    tap((index) => this.setActiveTab(index)),
    map((index) => ({index}))
  );
  this.state.connect(tabChanges$);

  // start tracking tabs
  this.tabs.notifyOnChanges();
  this.tabContents.notifyOnChanges();
}
```

- **tap** to cast type since QueryList.changes outputs
- **tap** again to assign values to children
- **switchMap** to react to children change

  - **merge** with rested(...) array to subscribe to every component
- **startWith** to have default value when nothing is clicked yet