# Achieving Interpolation in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi I am new to angular 2 and typescript and am trying to add html inside the tags of a component. This is what I have so far:

```
Component({
    selector: 'chart',
    templateUrl: './app/chart/chart.component.html'
})

export class Chart {
}
```

The html has the following strcuture:

```
<div class='chart-container'></div>
```

What I would like is to use the component in the following way:

```
<chart>
 <p>'Hello World'</p>
</chart>
```

When angular parses this code it should display the following:

```
  <chart>
     <div class='chart-container'>
          <p>'Hello World'</p>
      </div>
  </chart>
```

In angular 1 this was achieved via directive interpolation.Is there any way to achieve this in angular 2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a component as an 'argument' to another component in Angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34575897/passing-a-component-as-an-argument-to-another-component-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 4):

chart.component.html should look like

```
  <div class='chart-container'>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
```

to achieve what you want.